# Provide more meaningful error message when user is logged off

Tags: feature-request, error-message, logout

When you're in the middle of the edit process of anything (tested on editing my own question) and you're logged off during that (on another tab, etc.) you'll see "*An error has occured during posting*" error (or something similar).

Could this be changed to something more meaningful (like in many, many other web pages in the very same conditions), e.g.:  "*It seems, you have been logged off (possibly in another tab). Login again and submit this form*", or something similar?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not entirely convinced, that this is a duplicate of a question you mentioned. In my case, refreshing the page does not bring any change and my situation has nothing to do with cache. But, fine... you're welcome to have your own opinion! :]

Comment: Both are the same issue of being logged out, as far as I can see.

Comment: OK. But that message is 4 years old. What about unwritten rule, that if some bug isn't fixed after a year, one can ask similar question (to stimulate dev team?) and that question shouldn't be marked as duplicate? I think I heard stuff like this (that we should ask such semi-duplicate-stimulate questions) a few times around here.

Comment: No such rule, to bump old question one can edit or start a bounty.

Comment: @trejder Please avoid duplicating bugs. It makes our work *much* more tedious.

Comment: @Sklivvz I don't think he did this on purpose.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, that was a reply to "[...] one can ask similar question (to stimulate dev team?) [...]"

Comment: @Sklivvz I have my private opinion about bugs not being handled _in any way_ for **four years**. Especially, if it comes to a bug such "terribly hard to handle" like changing one error message to another. So, while I generally agree with you and promise to not do the same in future, I personally think, that talking about too much work in context of such simple bug not being fixed for so long, is a bit strange.

Comment: There are 3995 bugs awaiting triage at the moment--adding more will *not* make a difference, let me assure you. Furthermore, it would *not* make things better for other bugs that might merit more attention than yours.